# The same flag for an interrupt

Tags: stm32, interrupts, cortex-m, stm32f10x, flag

I think I'm mixed up a bit in NVIC of stm32 MCUs. I took a look in the SPI.h of the [STM32F10x standard peripheral library](http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF257890). I don't know that why while there is `SPI_I2S_IT_RXNE` for checking the status of recieved buffer we have `SPI_I2S_FLAG_RXNE` flag for this porpuse?

look:

[image: figure1]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `SPI_I2S_FLAG*` flags are used in polling mode, while  `SPI_I2S_IT*` flags are for interrupt mode.

See here for more details: http://web.eece.maine.edu/~hummels/classes/ece486/docs/libperiph_doc/group__SPI__Group5.html

Comment: AVR controller have something similar to this. If, for example, you are currently performing an ADC conversion then a flag will be set until the process is complete. However, an additional flag will be set once the conversion is complete to indicate an interrupt would have been triggered (if global interrupts were enabled). The interrupt *is* triggered of course if global interrupts were enabled.